# Timeout Error in AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am working on a Lex bot which is used for creating tickets. Problem is that the ticket creation takes time and I want to return the info which I get after ticket is created to the user but I am getting below error:

> ERROR: An error occurred (DependencyFailedException) when calling the
>   PostText operation: Invalid Bot Configuration: Lambda request did not
>   complete within permissible time (30 seconds).

However I have already set 5 mins in the `Timeout` of the Lambda function.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to rethink the way you’re creating tickets.  Bots must be designed to be very responsive.  AWS Lex limits to 30 seconds timeout.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47570834/1715121

Comment: 30 seconds is too less...

Comment: I think more than that will give a bad experience to your users. Don’t you think?

Comment: yes, that is indeed true. thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlikely the lambda, lex limited to 30 seconds.

look around for more exception, refer to [`runtime post text's`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) and [`runtime post content's`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html)
*`Error section`*